# Mongodb compare two fields with matched fields value aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having problems in my query, The parameter I am passing are voucherId, and userId, I need to check if that user exceeded the limitedQuantityPerUser. If yes, exclude this voucher. But I am having problems comparing the matching fields, example if voucherId is **'aaa'**, check if the **quantityBrought > limitedQuantityPerUser.**

I have tried this

```
vouchers.find({
         'status': {
          $in: ['OP', 'WG', 'LO', 'SO']
        },
        'details.userReachedLimitedQuantity': {
          $ne: userId
        },
      }, fields, {
        sort: {
          'order': 1
        }
      }
```

But this will give me all the result where userId not equal in the list. not exactly what I need. Is it better to solve using aggregate?

Example resource JSON file

```
[{
        "_id": "111",
        "details": {
            "limitedQuantityPerUser": "3",
            "userReachedLimitedQuantity": [{
                    "userId": "aaa",
                    "quantityBrought": "2"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "bbb",
                    "quantityBrought": "1"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "ccc",
                    "quantityBrought": "3"
                }
            ],
            "status": "OP"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "222",
        "details": {
            "limitedQuantityPerUser": "2",
            "userReachedLimitedQuantity": [{
                    "userId": "eee",
                    "quantityBrought": "2"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "bbb",
                    "quantityBrought": "1"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "vvv",
                    "quantityBrought": "2"
                }
            ],
            "status": "OP"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation to check whether specified `userId` exceeded defined limit.

```
db.vouchers.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$details.userReachedLimitedQuantity",
                        as: "user",
                        in: {
                            $or: [
                                { $ne: [ "$$user.userId", userId ] },
                                { $lte: [ "$$user.quantityBrought", "$details.limitedQuantityPerUser"  ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) takes an array of boolean values as a parameter. You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to transform your `userReachedLimitedQuantity` into such boolean values checking `userId` and `quantityBrought` fields.

So if any element is `false` then it means that that user's `quantityBrought` is greater than `limitedQuantityPerUser`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I got this error when trying to use it 

MongoError: $allElementsTrue's argument must be an array, but is null, I tried to add bracket [] between { $map } but, still got the same error

Comment: Hi, do you know how to only project the matched 'user Id' and its 'quantityBrought'. Because of the userReachedLimitedQuantity might get bigger and bigger in time

Comment: I managed to get your code working by using double [ [ ] ] to wrap the { $map} content.

Comment: Looks like adding double bracket will not work too, because in documentation [ [ false ] ], "isAllTrue" : true. to me, allElementsTrue doesn corp well with $map

Comment: @ThomasKim I've tested my solution on those documents you pasted, I guess that you have some other documents that have a different schema and that's why you're getting this null, any chance that you can filter them out before you apply above `$match` ?

Comment: you are right, yes. the other documents have different schema. So I should do a $filter before $match. is that what you meant right :)

Comment: Even thought didn't solve my case, but I think you are give the correct answer to the question. I will mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

No a perfect answer, but I did the filter in the result of mongod query

```
// Only take matched userId's quantityPurchased
const newResult = result.filter(val => {
  if (!val.details.userReachedLimitedQuantity) {
    return val;
  }
  val.details.userReachedLimitedQuantity= val.details.userReachedLimitedQuantity.filter((o) => {
    return (String(o.userId) == userId)
  });
  if (val.details.userReachedLimitedQuantity[0].quantityBrou < val.details.limitedQuantityPerUser) {
    return val;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```